# Trying to call multiple dispatchers on useffect

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to call multiple dispatchers on useEffect from extraReducers,  this way seems not to work.
How can I call two or more dispatchers differently?

I call this from a functional component:

```
 useEffect(() => {
     dispatch(getCourseOneAsync())
     dispatch(getCourseTwoAsync())
 }, [dispatch]);
```

Here are the reducers:

```
extraReducers: {
        [getCourseOneAsync.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            return action.payload.courses;
        },
        [getCourseTwoAsync.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            return action.payload.courses2;
        }
```

Comment: Is there any error? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to make a cascade dropdown, and for some reason, the dispatcher returns only one reducer when I call them from useEffect function. I want to call two dispatchers at the same time to fill the dropdown lists. @slideshop2

Answer (score 0):

From my point, the function inside `dispatch` and the name of `extraReducer` should be the same. I edited)

Comment: Thank you @Mukhridin, I've messed the namings on the question, but on the code the namings are the same, i have issues when i call two dispatchers at the same time on useEffect function.

Comment: @NaimAjro [here](https://vladi-strilets.medium.com/how-to-dispatch-multiple-async-actions-in-one-function-in-redux-16c4e6b3f2fc) I have found something useful for you)